# Building zlib libz.a for 32 bit

Tags: c++, mingw, zlib

I am trying to compile a 32-bit version (MinGW) of a program I wrote using zlib. Until now, I've never has to compile for 32-bit so the version of zlib I compiled from source (libz.a) is 64-bit. I tried to rerun the makefile in the zlib-1.2.5 directory but it only compiles a 64bit version of libz.a.

I can't seem to find an option to build 32-bit.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Jeffrey Kevin Pry

Comment: Generic advice: `./configure --help`

Comment: I know it's way old, but what about using `CFLAGS`/`CXXFLAGS` with `-m32` or `-m64` respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I had to get the 32bit version of MinGW and compile it with that. I was using MinGW64.

Answer (score 6):

Checking the configure file, you can see some env.

On 64bit debian, following command line will build the 32bit version of libz

```
CFLAGS=-m32 ./configure
```

Comment: That's the only way I know if you want to build it in a x86_64 system.

Answer (score 0):

Using `CFLAGS=-32` won't do it for me, `configure` script still shouts out telling me to use `win32/Makefile.gcc` instead all the time.

---

The recent version of zlib is 1.2.11, so it should be minimal gap of difference up until today. Without any context on system, the following might be useful for other users facing this similar problem these days.

I cross compile on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04), and target 32-bit version of zlib to be produced. What I did is as follows.

1. `./configure` (this is just to let us have required file to building process, we will be using different Makefile though)
2. Modify `win32/Makefile.gcc` for its `PREFIX=i686-w64-mingw32-` (for 64-bit you change it to `PREFIX=x86_64-w64-mingw32-`.
3. `make -fwin32/Makefile.gcc`
4. Install to your desire location via `make install -fwin32/Makefile.gcc SHARED_MODE=1 INCLUDE_PATH=/tmp/zlib-win32/include LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/zlib-win32/lib BINARY_PATH=/tmp/zlib-win32/bin`. Notice that you need to specify `INCLUDE_PATH`, `LIBRARY_PATH`, and `BINARY_PATH`. `BINARY_PATH` will contains result .dll file.